# laravel localization does not work with paramters

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

I have a multilingual project with English and Persian languages, While Persian is configured as locale for my project. localization files under *lang* directory in *resources* for both languages works fine except for parameters that I define.

under *resources > lang* in each language directory I created a general.php that returns associative array of my keywords and their replacements. It works fine but when if my key word contains a parameter it does not replace the parameter keywork.

Persian language general.php file

```
<?php
// general.php
return [
    'sending for' => ':attribute ارسال برای',

    'attributes' => [
         'ahmad' => 'احمد'
    ],
];
?>

// index.blade.php
{{ __('sending for', ['attribute' => 'ahmad']) }};

// result of index page
ارسال برای ahmad
```

however I define keyword 'ahmad' in attributes array of general.php file but it still returns key not the value

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

```
{{ __('sending for', ['attribute' => 'general.attributes.ahmad']) }};
```